# ASP.NET MVC DefaultModelBinder with nested lists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, defaultmodelbinder

I have a View with a table representing an employee's timesheet. Days across the top, projects down the side, with each day/project intersection containing two values for regular hours and overtime.

The (simplified) class definitions for the page model are:

```
public class TimesheetFormModel {
    public List<Project> Projects;
    // other things...
}
public class Project {
    public string Name;
    public List<WorkUnit> WorkUnits;
}
public class WorkUnit {
    public DateTime Date;
    public decimal RegularHours;
    public decimal OvertimeHours;
}
```

The form elements on the page are named as follows in an attempt to get the DefaultModelBinder to pick up on them.

```
model.Projects[0].Name // "New Project"
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[0].Date // "5/23/2009 12:00:00 AM"
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[0].RegularHours // 0
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[0].OvertimeHours // 0

model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[1].Date // "5/24/2009 12:00:00 AM"
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[1].RegularHours // 0
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[1].OvertimeHours // 0

model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[2].Date // "5/25/2009 12:00:00 AM"
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[2].RegularHours // 0
model.Projects[0].WorkUnits[2].OvertimeHours // 0

// etc.
```

When the view is submitted however, the `model` parameter isn't being completely populated. `model.Projects` contains projects, but the `Project`'s `WorkUnits` field is empty. Does the `DefaultModelBinder` support nested collections like I'm trying to do? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I eventually figured out why `DefaultModelBinder` wasn't picking up on the properties of `WorkUnit`: Because they weren't *properties*, they were *fields*. `DefaultModelBinder` only works with properties. Changing the class definition of `WorkUnit` and `Project` to use fields made everything click:

```
public class Project {
    public IList<WorkUnit> WorkUnits { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WorkUnit {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal RegularHours { get; set; }
    public decimal OvertimeHours { get; set; }
}
```

(Note: The source code in the original question had Project.Name defined as a field, in my actual code it was a property. This is why the Projects list was getting populated but WorkUnits wasn't.)